# Space Complexity of Map

Tags: python, lambda, generator

The python community recommends using map with lambda instead of a loop where possible. For example:

Method 1: Using list comprehension

```
return [element*2 for element in myList]
```

Method 2: Using map with lambda

```
return list(map(lambda element: element*2, myList))
```

Method 3: While loop

```
i = 0
while i < len(myList):
    myList[i] *= 2
    i += 1
return myList
```

However, the space complexity is:

Method 1 Generator: O(n)

Method 2 Map: O(n)

Method 3 Loop: O(1)

Am I missing something? Why is using a generator or map superior?

Comment: "The python community recommends using map with lambda instead of a loop where possible" Not really, no.

Comment: Note, your generator is not a generator, it is a list comprehension.  If you had used a generator expression, it would be O(1) space complexity. Simlarly, `list(map(lambda element: element*2, myList))` creates a list from your `map` iterator, so of course, you won't gain any space efficiency, but if you just used the map iterator directly, it is O(1). Note, your loop is broken, and you should be using a for-loop here instead of a while-loop.

Comment: In addition to the comments above, methods 1 and 2 create a new list, while method 3 mutates the list in-place. This distinction is often more severe than O(n) vs O(1).

Answer (score 1):

The comments on your question already make abundantly clear what is wrong with the question.

But to answer "why is using a generator [..] superior?", at least in cases where it might be - since no solution is always the better one independent of context:

- generators can be passed around and have state, loops can't and don't (not by default anyway; you could add it, but you'd be building home-brew generators);
- generators can be composed and (if written properly to do so), still take advantage of parallelism, loops can only do that if the full functional composition was known beforehand - or you write the loop in a generator function, in which case you built a generator anyway.

And "why is using [..] map superior?", at least in cases where it might be - since no solution is always the better one independent of context:

- `map` is the right choice when you already have a function and an iterable and would just be writing a generator that did the same otherwise;
  i.e. `map(sqrt, xs)` vs `(sqrt(x) for x in xs)`
- `map` has some functionality that takes work and obfuscates what you are trying to do if  you have multiple iterable inputs from which the inputs for the function are selected.
  e.g. `map(pair, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], ['a', 'b', 'c'])` (where `pair` takes two arguments)

And, in general, the solution that's easier to understand and maintain is generally the better solution, even if another solution might perform slightly better. That performance gain vs. a gain in maintainability is a trade-off you must consider.